# How to keep up-do-date with a repo that I've forked?

Tags: git, version-control, github, fork, bitbucket

If I want to start a project by forking/cloning an existing git repo, and continue working on this new branch forever, how should my workflow be?

I will want to continue pulling the new commits from the repo I originally branched off.

Will it be

1. `git clone`
2. `git checkout -b myNewBranch`
3. *Make some changes and commit*
4. `git rebase master`
5. *Make some changes and commit*
6. `git rebase master`
7. ...

Comment: Sounds like you’re using Git wrong. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @MartinBean Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @jszakmeister Just seems a bass-ackwards way of using something that is already decentralised. Can you not just maintain multiple remotes, pull from one, and push to another with your changes?

Comment: @MartinBean You certainly can.  But, you might take such an approach to avoid having the "useless" merge commits when you bring in master to your branch.  The kernel guys use this approach, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, except you needs to actually set up another remote in order to get the updates from the original repository and then do fetches from that repository. 
I'm going to assume that you're forking someones repository to do this and if that is the case, then I would do

1. Fork the original authors repository in github using the button on the site (see image below).
2. On your own github username/repository page copy the address by the clone icon.
3. Locally, at the command line / terminal ... `git clone ...` and then `cd the_repo_name/`
4. `git checkout -b myNewBranch`
5. *Make some changes and add and commit them and then `git push origin master`*
6. Add the original_username as **another** remote, e.g. author (git remote add ....)
7. `git fetch author master` # Get updates into your staging area.
8. `git rebase author/master` # Replay your local changes on top of the new updates
9. Resolve any conflicts
10. *Make some changes and commit and then `git push origin master`*
11. `git fetch author master`
12. `git rebase author/master`
13. Resolve any conflicts
14. ...

Notes:

`git remote -v` is useful to show existing remote(s).
steps 9,13,... will only be necessary when the same lines of code are edited (conflict).
step 8 is probably most critical:  You can be in any branch and 'pull in' the latest changes form another with `git rebase git_repo_src/branch_name`, rebase will 'save away' your changes, add the new changes in and then replay your edits on time.  You will need to resolve merge conflicts if the same lines are edited (usually not).  This means manually editing the files.

Adding another git remote example:  `git remote add author smithb/repo_name.git`

Where the items are in github:

```
Fork                         Cloning - copy (ctrl-c, etc.) the HTTPS: Clone URL 
Click the button "Fork"       (click the button in some browsers prob. flash):
in the original repo.        Then, at a local terminal window `git clone <paste>`
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: Thanks~! What would you name the remote from which you originally forked from?

Comment: When adding it in order to get the updates I would call it something like 'author', 'source', etc.  I am tempted by 'original' but it seems too close to 'origin' y'know.

Comment: Added example of adding remote in the notes.

Comment: @Nyxynyx I call it "upstream" in my repos.

Comment: +1 
That works!  src and original_author are another couple of options.